# Change flush mode in Spring Boot tests when @DataJpaTest in use?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jpa, spring-boot-test

How do you get Spring tests using `@DataJpaTest` to use `COMMIT` flush mode?  This is not working for my Spock unit tests:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest(properties = "spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=COMMIT")
class MyJpaTestSpec extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager

    def "test flush mode"() {
        expect:
        // confirming that flushMode is still AUTO even though I configured COMMIT
        entityManager.flushMode == FlushModeType.AUTO
    }
}
```

`entityManager.getFlushMode()` continues to return `AUTO`.

This is with Spring Boot 2.2.2 with a dependency on spring-test:5.2.2.RELEASE.

I also have a configuration class:

```
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@SpringBootConfiguration
class MyConfiguration {
}
```

And `src/test/resources/application.yml` (Gradle) appears to being read because certain configurations are being picked up (such as the datasource), but the `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode` property appears to be ignored from the config file while executing the `@DataJpaTest` tests.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    # seems to be ignored for @DataJpaTests
    properties:
        org.hibernate.flushMode: COMMIT
```

I've tried hacks like adding a `@PostConstruct` in `MyConfiguration` to call `setFlushMode()` on the `entityManager` but that doesn't work either.  By the time the test is run, it has reverted back to `AUTO` flush mode.  (I'm guessing it reverts back to AUTO for every new session.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tried this before even posting the question, but it turns out this appears to be a Spring bug that has recently been fixed.  I upgraded to Spring Boot v2.2.6 (which uses spring-test v5.2.5).  When I posted my question, I was using Spring Boot v2.2.2.  The upgrade from v2.2.2 to v2.2.6 has solved the problem.  On v2.2.6, `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode` is not ignored in my test like it was with v2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you manage to set the flush mode to `COMMIT` for your `@DataJpaTest` tests, it won't work as you might expect. If you check the documentation for the `@DataJpaTest` annotation, you will find this:

> By default, tests annotated with `@DataJpaTest` are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

What it means is that the transaction used during the test won't commit at the end. Hence the pending changes most likely won't be flushed if the flush mode is set to flush when the current running transaction is committed.

I think you have two options.

1. Flush manually whenever you need
2. Set Hibernate specific `property org.hibernate.flushMode` to `ALWAYS`